# count weekdays between sys.date and each date in column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a list of dates in the column "thedate".

for each value in this column, i need the difference in weekdays between that and Sys.Date(), then multiplied by 195.

I want something like:

Sys.Date() "2017-11-21"

```
thedate    | weekdays 
-----------+--------------------------
2017-11-21 | 0 
2017-11-22 | 195 
2017-11-23 | 390 
2017-11-24 | 585
2017-11-25 | 585 (because it's a saturday)
```

My code is as follows:

```
dates <- as.Date("2017-11-21"):as.Date("2020-11-20")
forecasting <- data.frame(thedate = as.Date(dates, origin = "1970-01-01"))
forecasting$weekdays <- 195 * sum(!weekdays(seq(Sys.Date(), forecasting$thedate, "days")) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"))
```

seq(Sys.Date(), forecasting$thedate, "days") throws an error back:
"'to' must be of length 1" presumably because i'm referring to the entire column, but I don't know how else to count the weekdays for each column.

is there a way to adjust this so that for each date in the "thedate" column I get the difference in weekdays between that and the sys.date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a function that calculates the number of business days between a certain date and Sys.Date():

```
nr_bdays <- function(day){
library(lubridate)
  if(day<=Sys.Date()){
    x <- seq.Date(day, Sys.Date(), by="day")
    } else {x <- seq.Date(Sys.Date(), day, by="day")}
return(length(x[grep("1|2|3|4|5", wday(x, week_start=1))])) #counts number of days Monday to Friday excluding weekends 
}
```

For instance

```
day <- ymd("2017-11-10")
nr_bdays(day)
#[1] 8
```

In vectorised form you can do:

```
dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2017-11-21"), as.Date("2017-12-20"), by="day")
sapply(dates, nr_bdays)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  4  4  5  6  7  8  9  9  9 10 11 12 13 14 14 14 15 16 17 18 19 19 19 20 21 22
```

Comment: thanks but i'm still unable to apply it to an entire column as the function can only take one value at a time. Do you know how I could apply this to an entire column so that I have the difference between sys.date() and each date in 'forecasting$thedate'?

Comment: awesome. using what you gave I did forecasting$weekdays <- 195 * (sapply(seqdates, nr_wdays) - 1) and it got me exactly what i'm after. Thanks

Comment: note that in germany my locale is set so that the week starts on Sunday (1) in the wday() function. I made one more change to the code so that the week starts with number 1=Monday.

Comment: Oh thanks - before you made that change i checked what it did on the return and it seemed to work fine as it is. I did the -1 because i wanted to start adding the 195 starting on the second value

Comment: I checked, the function wday() had set it up like that by default, that means all locales, so u should be covered, it was valid command. Like this it is more readable, 1 for monday, 2 for Tuesday up to 5 for friday